# Hide libcamera info in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I have a python script that is using PiCamera2 and I want to hide the information that is given by libcamera (i presume)
Is there a way to do this, I can't find anything about it online

[Screenshot Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eikCU.png)

```
[10:00:05.468381088] [120668]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3700-f30ad033
[10:00:05.581751436] [120822]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1368 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media1
[10:00:05.590128112] [120668]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1029 configuring streams: (0) 640x480-XBGR8888
[10:00:05.591056440] [120822]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:759 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 2028x1520-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 2028x1520-pBCC
```

Comment: Please post the code instead of posting the link with the code

Answer (score 4):

In PiCamera2 there are 2 things which can log to your console.

The first one is Picamera2 python module which log level can be set by:

```py
Picamera2.set_logging(Picamera2.ERROR)
```

The second one is libcamera (C++ library underpinning Picamare2), its log level can be changed by setting the environment variable **LIBCAMERA_LOG_LEVELS** (this is most likely to be your case). In python, you can set an environment variable this way:

```py
import os

os.environ["LIBCAMERA_LOG_LEVELS"] = "3"
```

You can use different numbers for different log levels:

"0" - DEBUG, "1" - INFO, "2" - WARN, "3" - ERROR, "4" - FATAL

Comment: setting `LIBCAMERA_LOG_LEVELS` appears to be the only one of these that has any effect for me. Setting it to `"2"` (*WARN*) turns off most logging noise but does keep usage warnings. Your litres per 100 km may vary, though ...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the logging level of `PiCamera`.

```
# Will only log output when an error happens
picam2 = Picamera2(verbose_console=0)
```

Comment: Hm, doesnt seem to be doing anything

Comment: @Xioto Can you post the code you are running? It is very hard to tell you what is going wrong otherwise

Comment: Note that attempting to use `verbose_console` now emits the warning *verbose_console parameter is no longer used, use Picamera2.set_logging instead*